# How do I nicely curve two perpendicular rectangles?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, geometry

I have two rectangles that I want to smoothly curve along the green line I've marked.

Ends (marked red circles) must stay in place.

How do I do this? I am begginer to Blender.

[image: Blender preview]

I've joined the two rectangles and tried to bevel the edges but the outer edge is limited to where the edges actually joined and the inner edge I can't even bevel.

[image: Blender preview]

Comment: If you do the green curve it needs to be one object, not 2. You could use a bevel on a L shape then extrude along normals to give it thickness?

Comment: I've joined both rectangles but really can't bevel the inner edge and the outer edge is somewhat limited to where the edges joined... (Edited my post above)

Answer (score 4):

Do it this way instead. Create this shape:

[image]

Bevel the edge:

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to extrude along faces:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Have to be careful with this method as the user might unintentionally flip the normals like this https://snipboard.io/BYqpfG.jpg

Comment: Sure, he'll need to recalculate the normals afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Merge the faces on the sides like this:

[image]

You can also start only with the top rectangle without the curve part and use the spin tool to curve it 90º

[image]